# How to use new Scoped Animation Modifiers in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, has anyone had any luck using the new [`animation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:body:)) view modifier that was [announced](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10156/?time=1510) at WWDC'23? I must be missing something very basic, because I can't get it to work for me.

Here's a simple example I have set up. I would expect that the `animation` view modifier would override the (redundant) `withAnimation` blocks in the Buttons, below. So the "Reveal" button should be using a very quick (0.01 second) spring animation to offset the red rectangle. Why doesn't this work?

```swift
struct ScopedAnimation: View {
    @State private var offset = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                Text("Hello")
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                Color.green
                    .animation(.bouncy(duration: 0.01)) {
                        $0.offset(x: offset)
                    }
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            Button("Reveal") {
                withAnimation(.bouncy(duration: 0.5)) { offset = -100 }
            }
            Button("Reset") {
                withAnimation(.none) { offset = 0 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```